# Who is an owner of data rendered by IDataObject::GetData?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, ole

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-getdata) wording on that matter is somewhat confusing. First it states:

> The caller then assumes responsibility for releasing the STGMEDIUM structure

then in parameters description:

> A pointer to the STGMEDIUM structure that indicates the storage medium containing the returned data through its tymed member, and the responsibility for releasing the medium through the value of its pUnkForRelease member.

I can't draw a reliable conclusion that I'm an owner from that and can modify the data without copying it. Obligation to release through pUnkForRelease makes returning the medium handle (e.g. HBITMAP or whatever) from a function impossible. Thus my ownership of the data is restricted, if it exists at all.

I don't want to make a needless copy. I think an implementer of IDataObject have to make a copy of data even if it will be identical to the source data, because nothing says that a user isn't allowed to modify it. Then why should I copy it again? Am I an owner of it?

Comment: The following sentence is important: *"If `pUnkForRelease` is `NULL`, the receiver of the medium is responsible for releasing it"*. In other words: You can arrange for being the sole owner of the data returned. Which also implies that you hold a *copy* of the data managed by the `IDataObject`, not a reference to it.

Comment: @IInspectable, I've read in the docs it's a provider's privilege to decide who is responsible for releasing data (which may imply ownership and the right to modify data). You can read this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-releasestgmedium) — _"The provider indicates that the receiver of the medium is responsible for freeing the medium by specifying NULL for the punkForRelease structure member."_ Thus I'm not sure your words are true.

Comment: I believe the documentation for `ReleaseStgMedium` makes it clear: if `pUnkForRelease` is not null, the provider owns the data; if it's null, the caller does. In the former case, you could delay calling `pUnkForRelease->Release()` until you are done with the data; but if for some reason you cannot, then you'd need to make a copy.

Comment: GetData builds data for you in the STGMEDIUM structure. Just call ReleaseStgMedium on it when you're finished with it. If you want to modify the IDataObject, use SetData. Not sure what you're after.